# SpriteKit multi part Sprite changes Path badly internally

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

First question ever and I would have an image if I had 10 reputation? Anyway I would have given the artwork as well but those are images too! LOL

Anyway ---- SpriteKit the creation of a multi part Sprite with multiple physicsBodys seems to change the path I give it into something else after it gets into the physicsBody. The result is unpredictable behaviour because the edges are not what you think.  Below is the code and a screen shot showing what I create in terms of the path and what SpriteKit thinks the path is once it had been passed through 'bodyWithPolygonFromPath:'.
![enter image description here][1]
Does anybody know how to fix this behaviour?

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
        [self initializeWorldPhysicalFeatures];
        [self createLoopAroundWorld];
        [self createContent];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) createContent
{
    float desiredScale = 0.25;
    CGPoint desiredLocation = CGPointMake(50.0f, 50.0f);

    NSArray *verticesBody1 = @[
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(293.000000,     199.699974)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(137.660156, 193.579552)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(128.737549, 142.721581)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(24.000000, 116.599998)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(24.000000, 56.599998)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(101.000000, 10.300011)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(491.000000, 10.899986)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(564.599976, 51.300011)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(569.378418, 107.260216)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(426.149414, 133.930321)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(410.000000, 175.500023)]
                               ];

    NSArray *verticesBody2 = @[
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(532.400024, 218.799973)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(535.900024, 212.600021)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(388.599976, 150.299973)],
                               [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(378.000000, 178.199997)],
                               ];

    UIBezierPath *body1Path = [self buildPathFromVertices:verticesBody1];
    UIBezierPath *body2Path = [self buildPathFromVertices:verticesBody2];

    CGAffineTransform scaleAndTranslate = [MyScene buildTransformWithScale:desiredScale
                                                               andLocation:desiredLocation];

    [body1Path applyTransform:scaleAndTranslate];
    [body2Path applyTransform:scaleAndTranslate];

    CGPoint tankBodyPosition = CGPointMake(0.393280, 0.332581);
    CGPoint tankBodyTransformedPosition = CGPointApplyAffineTransform (tankBodyPosition,scaleAndTranslate);

    CGPoint tankBarrelPosition = CGPointMake(388.723633, 147.831482);
    CGPoint tankBarrelTransformedPosition = CGPointApplyAffineTransform   (tankBarrelPosition,scaleAndTranslate);

    SKSpriteNode *tankBodySprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"TankRight_Body.png"];
    [tankBodySprite setScale:desiredScale];
    tankBodySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    tankBodySprite.position = tankBodyTransformedPosition;
    tankBodySprite.zPosition = 1;
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:body1Path.CGPath];
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody.mass = 5;
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody.friction = 0.5;
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    tankBodySprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    SKSpriteNode *tankBarrelSprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"TankRight_Barrel.png"];
    [tankBarrelSprite setScale:desiredScale];
    tankBarrelSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    tankBarrelSprite.position = tankBarrelTransformedPosition;
    tankBarrelSprite.zPosition = 1;
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:body2Path.CGPath];
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody.mass = 1;
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody.friction = 0.5;
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    [self addChild:tankBodySprite];
    [self addChild:tankBarrelSprite];

    CGPoint tankBarrelPinJointAnchor = CGPointMake(110.79742431640625, 54.3955078125);
    SKPhysicsJointPin *currentPinJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin   jointWithBodyA:tankBodySprite.physicsBody
                                                                    bodyB:tankBarrelSprite.physicsBody
                                                                  anchor:tankBarrelPinJointAnchor];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:currentPinJoint];

    // My DEBUG code to show where the REAL paths are.
    [self drawPath:body1Path
         withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self drawPath:body2Path
         withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

- (UIBezierPath *) buildPathFromVertices:(NSArray *) arrayOfVertices
{
    NSUInteger numberOfPoints = [arrayOfVertices count];
    UIBezierPath *builtPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [builtPath moveToPoint:[arrayOfVertices[0] CGPointValue] ];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < numberOfPoints ; ++i)
    {
        [builtPath addLineToPoint:[arrayOfVertices[i] CGPointValue]];
    }
    [builtPath closePath];
    return builtPath;
}

- (void) initializeWorldPhysicalFeatures
{
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.03);
}

- (void) createLoopAroundWorld
{
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
}

+ (CGAffineTransform) buildTransformWithScale:(float)   aScale
                                  andLocation:(CGPoint) aFinalDestination
{
    // We need to have a transform that:
    // 1. Scales the object.
    // 2. Moves the object to it's final destination.
    CGAffineTransform scaleMatrix     = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(aScale, aScale);
    CGAffineTransform finalMoveMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(aFinalDestination.x,   aFinalDestination.y);
    CGAffineTransform compoundMatrix  = CGAffineTransformConcat(finalMoveMatrix,  scaleMatrix);
    return compoundMatrix;
}

- (void) drawPath:(UIBezierPath *) aPath
        withColor:(UIColor *)      aColor
{
    SKNode *parentNode = [SKNode new];
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
    shape.path = aPath.CGPath;
    shape.name = @"Test_Object";
    shape.strokeColor = aColor;
    shape.lineWidth = 0.1;
    shape.zPosition = 99;
    [parentNode addChild:shape];
    [self addChild:parentNode];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Comment: Post a link to the image, and someone with higher rep can insert it for you. Or wait until your question gets one more upvote, then you can insert it yourself. :)

Comment: The problem isn't that I lose control of the CGPath, ie. release artifacts etc.  My call to drawPath: withColor: post creation of the SKPhysicsBody, produces the exact path around the artwork that I intended. It is the skView.showsPhysics = YES; call in the View Controller that shows me what SpriteKit THINKS is the path I passed it.  Mine is what I intended, SpriteKits is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood the question, but it sounds like the path changes unpredictably. One reason could be this:

```
.. = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:body1Path.CGPath];
```

The [UIBezierPath docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/CGPath) for the `CGPath` property state that:

> This property contains a snapshot of the path at any given point in
>   time. Getting this property returns an immutable path object that you
>   can pass to Core Graphics functions. **The path object itself is owned
>   by the UIBezierPath object and is valid only until you make further
>   modifications to the path.**

So you need to create a copy of the path and properly release the copy as well:

```
CGPathRef copiedPath = CGPathCreateCopy(body1Path.CGPath);
.. = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:copiedPath];
CGPathRelease(copiedPath); 
copiedPath = nil;
```

Same goes for all other uses of `bezierPath.CGPath` in your code. You don't own the path, it's memory is subject to being modified or released by UIBezierPath, resulting in unpredictable behavior unless you create a copy of the path object returned by UIBezierPath.

Comment: So nobody has ran into any issues with using Polygons for a PhysicsBody????  I know all the examples out there seem to favor simplistic outlines of rectangles or squares but I am drawing outlines around artwork in Inkscape and splitting complex objects into pieces that are glued together with joints of various types.  Collision wise it may slow things down but with the InkScape code I have developed I will tweek game objects until they act properly and at an acceptable speed.  If drawing boxes and circles is the only solution then so be it but I wanted to know what others know?